# Replacing string in Word document using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a .docx template with a string I want to replace (like serialNumber, date, author, etc.) using Excel VBA.

```vb
Private Sub Create()

    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Dim file As String

    Set MaFeuille = Sheets("Information")

    file = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "nomfichier.docx"
    
    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With word_app
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    End With

    Set word_fichier = word_app.documents.Open(file)
    word_app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    word_app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            
    With word_app.Selection.Find
        .Text = "blabla"
        .Replacement.Text = "coucou"
    End With
        
End Sub
```

The Word file is launched but the string is not replaced.

Comment: Please provide details of what's not working - Is there an error? Or just not doing what you are expecting it to be? Note - 1) I believe you mean `With word_fichier.Range.Find`, the 2 `ClearFormatting` line should be unneccessary and can be deleted. 2) You only specify the `.Text` and `.Replacement.Text` property of the `Find` object but you did not `.Execute`.

Comment: I edited, and 1) wdym by .Execute ?  dont know how to use this line, 2) I deleted the ```ClearFormatting``` lines 3) what's the difference between ```With word_app.Selection.Find``` and ```With word_app.Range.Find```

Comment: 1) You need `.Execute` if you want to perform the replace, as for now your code only specify what string to find and what string to replace with but not the action of replacing it.  2) My comment said `word_fichier.Range.Find`, `word_fichier` is the word document that you opened so I'm assuming you want to replace words in that document, in that case then you will access its `Find` object by `word_fichier.Range.Find`. `word_app.Selection.Find` means finding within the selection. (which is not possible because `word_app` is opened programmatically) @julien1h

Comment: You have used a word enumeration 'wdWindowsStateMaximize' but have declared your word object as late bound (CreateObject).  Consequently, unless you have a reference to Word which you haven't mentioned, 'wdWindowsStateMaximize' is undefined and hence zero.  This means that you are not using Option Explicit at the start of your modules.  You are stupid if you do not do so.

Comment: You may find that installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and looking at the code inspections to be an enlightening experience.

Comment: i tried to write smthg like this ```With word_app.Range.Find.Execute``` instead of ```With word_app.Selection.Find``` and now i have a 438 error

Comment: @julien1h Please read what I wrote carefully. - `word_fichier.Range.Find`, not `word_app.Range.Find`. `.Execute` can be added after `.Replacement.Text = "coucou"`, before `End With`.

Comment: @freeflow thanks, i found these lines on the web. Unfortunately i cant install anything on my company computer :(

Comment: @Raymond Wu, ok sorry, miss read :(, so i tried this ```With word_fichier.Range.Find``` and the ```.Execute``` before the ```End With```. Still the same result, i edit my primary post to be clear

Comment: If you can't install anything on your company PC then you shouldn't be trying to write VBA macros.  If your company does support your writing macros then installing RUbberduck for you is a must as it is a fantastic productivity gain with no risk attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Always declare all your variables, insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce this.
2. You are missing `.Execute` in the `Find` object, you also need to specify the `Replace` argument to perform the replace (instead of just find).
3. If you are late-binding, then you can't use enumeration that exist in Word library such as `wdWindowStateMaximize` without defining it manually so the alternative is to provide the value directly instead.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Create()

    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Set MaFeuille = Sheets("Information")
    
    Dim file As String
    file = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "nomfichier.docx"

    Dim word_app As Object
    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With word_app
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = 1 'value for wdWindowStateMaximize
    End With
    
    Dim word_fichier As Object
    Set word_fichier = word_app.Documents.Open(file)
    With word_fichier.Range.Find
        .Text = "blabla"
        .Replacement.Text = "coucou"
        .Execute Replace:=2 'value for wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, learnt a lot today !

Comment: @julien1h If you are not familiar with the object (Word in this case) then I suggest you add reference to it (`Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library` in this case) so that you can work with early-binding and benefit from the intelliSense from the editor. Also, always consult the documentation.